# Bigquery Count cells in a row conditionally to make a percentage

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I Have this in a table in Bigquery:

| element | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | green | brown | green |
| B | blue | green | blue |

I need to count the "green" for every elelement (count green in each row). And i need to make this output:

| element | %_green_per_row |
| --- | --- |
| A | 66% |
| B | 33% |

I´ll appreciate if anyone can help to do this on sql for bigquery. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select element, round(100 * array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), '"green"')) / 3, 2) as percent_green_per_row
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mikhail Berlyant. It worked correctly. Awesome!.